# distribution of sign(A)*B

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Let $A, B$ be normally distributed, independent random variables and $E(A)=E(B)=0$.

Let $C=sgn(A)*B$.

Show: $C$ has the same distribution as $B$.

I really don't know where to start here.. could someone please help me?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $B$ and $-B$ have the same distribution in this context?

Comment: calculate probabilities using conditioning (on the sign of A)

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D\subseteq\mathbb R$ denote some measurable set and start with:$$P(C\in D)=P(-B\in D\wedge A<0)+P(B\in D\wedge A=0)+P(B\in D\wedge A>0)$$also see my comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's find the p.d.f. for $C$
$$
f_C(x)=P_A(a\geqslant0)f_B(x)+P_A(a\lt 0)f_B(-x)=\frac{1}{2}f_B(x)+\frac{1}{2}f_B(x)=f_B(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Now I got that

$P(C<=x)=P(sign(A)*B<=x)=P(A>=0,B<=x) \cup P(A<0,B>=-x) = \\=P(B<=x)*(P(A>=0)+P(A<0)) = P(B<=x)$

Thank you for helping me!